No me carga el reproductor de youtube de mi app hecha en visual studio con capacitor-youtube-player
Buenas estoy teniendo problemas con el reproductor youtube de mi app , esta realizado con capacitor-youtube-player el cual se encuentra incorporado en mi proyecto sin embargo no soy capaz de que me funcione , tengo incorporadas correctamente todas las apis, he conectado mi dispositivo movil a android studio y cargado la app en el dispositivo me salen estos dos errores:

YoutubePlayerFragment   *****              E  [Youtube Player
Fragment]: onCreate
YoutubePlayerFragment   ****              E  [Youtube Player
Fragment]: initializeYoutubePlayer

Tambien he podido comprobar que mi version de capacitor-youtube-player y mi version de capacitor/core en teoria son incompatible lo cual no tiene sentido porque ambas estan actualizadas a la ultima version la version de mi capacitor/core es la 6.1 y la de capacitor-youtube-player es la 1.1.0 que en teoria tambien es la ultima por lo tanto no me deberia dar error , sin embargo tuve que utilizar el --force a la hora de instalar el capacitor-youtube-player ya que no me dejaba instalarlo por lo dicho un error de dependencias , ya nose si es error de mi codigo o realmente de las dependencias aunque me den conflicto ambas se encuentran en la última version.

El soporte para la reproducción de videos mediante los SDK de
reproductores integrados nativos de YouTube (para Android/iOS)
Finalizó el 1 de julio 2023. El proyecto capacitor-youtube-player utiliza un WebView para mostrar videos, por lo que debería usar YouTube IFrame Player API, aunque de acuerdo a los mensajes de error, esta usando la versión anterior del YouTube Player (usa YoutubePlayerFragment ):

YoutubePlayerFragment ***** E [Youtube Player Fragment]: onCreate

Para continuar admitiendo la reproducción de
videos de YouTube en aplicaciones móviles, el reproductor YouTube Iframe debe cargarse en una vista web.
Por lo tanto, se debe migrar para usar ahora YouTube IFrame Player API., este es un ejemplo minimo:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <!-- 1. The <iframe> (and video player) will replace this <div> tag. -->
    <div id="player"></div>

    <script>
      // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
      var tag = document.createElement('script');

      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

      // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
      //    after the API code downloads.
      var player;
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '390',
          width: '640',
          videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
          playerVars: {
            'playsinline': 1
          },
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
      }

      // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
      function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.playVideo();
      }

      // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
      //    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
      //    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
      var done = false;
      function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
          setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
          done = true;
        }
      }
      function stopVideo() {
        player.stopVideo();
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>

Revisa mi ejemplo:
https://github.com/Jorgesys/YouTube-Player-API-for-iframe-Embeds
